# Why the didReceiveRemoteNotification is not being called?

Tags: ios, cloudkit, subscription

I'm trying to create a subscription using CloudKit to fires every time a record is created. I have successfully created the subscription, I can see it in dashboard, but I've noticed that the print I have in *didReceiveRemoteNotification* was never printed!

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    print("oioioioioi")

    let viewController: CurrentEventController = self.window?.rootViewController as! CurrentEventController

    if let userInfo = userInfo as? [String: NSObject] {

        let notification: CKNotification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: userInfo)

        if (notification.notificationType == CKNotificationType.Query) {

            let queryNotification = notification as! CKQueryNotification

            let recordID = queryNotification.recordID

            viewController.fetchRecord(recordID!)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you successfully register for push notifications? What iOS version are you running? Device or simulator? Did you also implement didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time! I did register; using a iOS 9.3.2; send the record in the simulator (and sometimes, write directly in dashboard) and expects to see the notification in my iPhone; I did not implement this function, why should I? In another project I was able to see notifications without implementing it

Comment: I asked because if you implement it, the other method does not get called.